# TableView changes cell content while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I know, this is asked several times and it is answered everytime more than 1 time, but no one, of these solutions helped myself!

When my TableView opens, I can see one row of text, instead of >10! So I scroll down and 2 cells later its presented the right way! If I scroll up again, I can see the cell with this single line, is presenting everything right, too!
So, here is my question: What went wrong in my code?!

This is my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    AACTickerYellowCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[AACTickerYellowCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString * text = [self getTextAtIndex:indexPath];

    CGSize size = [self frameForText:text sizeWithFont:nil constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(260.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX)];

    [cell.textView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 260, size.height + 20)];
    cell.textView.text = text;

    return cell;
```

Comment: Please post tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

Comment: Please explain getTextAtIndex: too, as loading the data may take longer than the time taken to load the cells.

Comment: @MyJBMe have you tried my code?

Comment: @danh The code of Mirko Catalano worked at all! Thank you anyway! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like that and your problem disappear:

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    AACTickerYellowCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[AACTickerYellowCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString * text = [self getTextAtIndex:indexPath];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        CGSize size = [self frameForText:text sizeWithFont:nil constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(260.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX)];

        [cell.textView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 260, size.height + 20)];
        cell.textView.text = text;
    });
    return cell;
```

Comment: AWESOME, it works!!!! Thank you! :)
But, can you explain to me, what the dispatch-block does?

Comment: the problem is that the first cell is already made when you change the UI of your label, so you have to make block with this changes and push it in the main queue (that is the queue used for the UI) for do that in asynchrony time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed  **row**?

`NSString * text = [self getTextAtIndex:indexPath.row]`